# How to select specific controls within a selected rig

Tags: python, animation, select, hierarchy, maya

I would like to be able to select a global control for a rig and have the code search through the control hierarchy of that rig in order to isolate controls with specific keywords in the name. For example, I would like to select the global control, and then when I run the code, have the code isolate the root, spine, chest and shoulders in that order and store them for a separate function.

So far I have tried two methods:

import maya.cmds as cmds

allCurves = cmds.select(cmds.selectType(nurbsCurve=True))

In an attempt to select all the nurbs curves and then isolate them down to just the ones with "shoulder", "root", "spine" etc in their names, however, that ended up not selecting anything.

I have also tried:

import maya.cmds as cmds

children_joints = cmds.listRelatives(allDescendents=True, type='nurbsCurve')
cmds.select(children_joints, add=True)

in an attempt to select all the children of the global control and isolate it down using the above mentioned method/result. That did not work as intended, as the remaining nurbs curves are not direct children of the global control, only constrained by it, so while it did work when I selected the arm (It then selected the elbow, wrist etc), it did nothing when I selected the global control or root node.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.